# Euterpe precatoria getting brown spots and brown dry leafs

Tags: diagnosis, palm, browning

My Euterpe precatoria has had small brown spots on its leaves for some time now. Over time, these became larger and larger, turning into large brown spots. Recently, however, the green leaves have become completely brown and dry and die off after a while, causing the whole shoot to die.
Now, for the first time, a new leaf has also turned brown while it was still curled up and growing. After the shoot unfolded, several of the new leaves were already brown and dry.
It is in a rather loose soil with sand, perlite and expanded clay. Its pot is a so-called fabric pot with good ventilation and drainage.
It is kept in my indoor greenhouse all year round at a relative humidity of between 75-90% and a temperature of approx. 25-27 degrees Celsius (77F - 80.6F). The greenhouse also has a shading net (60%) so that they don't get too much direct sunlight.
I rarely fertilize them and when I do, I use a complete fertilizer plus extra iron fertilizer.
As far as I can see, it has no pests.
I've also spent several hours googling but I couldn't find any comparable symptoms. Unfortunately, there isn't much information about the Euterpe precatoria anyway.
I would be very grateful for any tips on what it might be missing.

[image: newest leaf]
[image: soil in a pot]

More images can be found at [imgur - more palm photos](https://imgur.com/a/pSQfJSn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like fertilizer burn to me. Also, palm trees prefer sandy loamy soils over highly draining gravel. The gravel retains too much moisture and fertilizer, which in turn is drying near your root area and remaining concentrated throughout their. Also, do you use correct NPK proportions? This looks more of oversaturated nutrition case.

Comment: Thanks, the small red, white and black stones you see on the top of the soil are really only on the top. There is a one to two cm thick layer of those on the top. The bigger expanded clay is distributed throughout the soil, together with a lot of sand. But yes, my soil is not very loamy. Do you think I should repot it as soon as possible?

Comment: I used 6%N 3%P 6%K together with a small amount of 6%N + 3% FE. It was really a small amount but I strongly guess you're right and it was too much. Me sad

Comment: The issue is with High Nitrogen and Iron amounts. Both of which, are highly corrosive in nature (especially if you are opting for foliar applications). I'd suggest to keep iron as sole nutrient in foliar spray, and apply Nitrogen based fertilizer to tender trunks instead during further applications.

Comment: Also, when fertilizing, the concentration of fertilizer, it's dilution and the duration of it's application are much more important than the actual ratios of fertilizer contents to ensure that you don't get burns.

Comment: Another thing: For sure repotting will help, add a bit of compost as well to improve retention capacity as also, repotting will help to make up for excess nutrients due to overfertilization.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be more careful with fertilizing in the future. Do you suggest a loam soil with  40–40–20% concentration of sand–silt–clay? Plus a few handful of compost from the compost container in my parents garden? Thank you very much for your kind help

Comment: Sounds good to me! All the best!

Comment: My little palm and I say thank you :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have one more question, how much loam would you add to the mix? 20%?

Comment: There's no such thing as fixed proportions in gardening. This mustn't be taken as some sort of chemistry. That being said, the soil must be able to hold nutrients as palms are heavy feeders and you're trying to grow them in containers. Your soil mustn't leach nutrients and must be firm enough to support the roots of growing plant. You can reduce your sand proportion to 25-30% and substitute loam as other half (i.e. 25-30%)